# Unsort Windows Forms DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

This Function:

```
dataGridView.Sort(this.dataGridView.Columns[1], ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

lets me sort a `DataGridView` and its works.

But as the story goes, the user can unsort this view.

There is no Databinding. The view gets a `List` and adds it, row by row.

So how do I unsort this `DataGridView`?

Comment: What do you mean by unsort? Arrange in some kind of random order?  If you want the order back how it was before you will somehow have to save that order somewhere and then reorder your list in that order.  Why would you want to do this though?

Comment: The program will scan an xml File. The positon of an Item in this List is the same as it is in the xml File.  (With Item one begins the List aand so forth). But if the List sort , this corrolation is Lost. Our team guess that there is an intresed for the user to get this orignal state back.

Comment: SO reread the file in the original order.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to unsort:

```
 this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```